# Returning the maximum value of a vector with for, if or function

Tags: r

How can I return the maximum value of a numerical vector of length 2 using ** for **, ** if ** or ** function ** in Rstudio?

I have done this:

```
  x <- c(100,500)
 for(x in x){print(x)}
```

But I can not get the output: the maximun value

thanks

Comment: you have function max(x)

Comment: Is this a homework question? Please add a note or tag either way. If it's not for homework, why are you limited to using *for*, *if*, and *or*? As Bea said, the obvious approach is to use max(x).

Comment: Yes, That is a homework question

Comment: I can use only: for if or function

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is a homework question.

I have to leave my office and so I don't have time to write out a code sample, but it will be good practice to try implementing on your own first.

Before your loop begins you can define a variable (biggest_X, or something) as zero or NULL and then within each iteration of the loop check if the current x is larger than biggest_X. If so, assign that value to biggest_X, and if not then do nothing. After the loop has completed, biggest_X will be the largest X value that occurred in the vector.